# How to add a cron job for selected hours

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I would like to add a cron job in google app engine that occurs every 5minutes but not every hour. Is that possible?

something like every 5minutes of hours 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,0

unix format would be something like that ... ? (not sure): 
*/5 0,7-23 * * *

The goal is to reduce the instances used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you even read the docs?  It's pretty much right in there.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

```
every 5 minutes from 7:00 to 0:00
```

Comment: oops. Sorry. I red the doc but didn't see this example. Thank you!!